# Pyinstaller and xdg-open

Tags: linux, bash, pyinstaller, linux-mint

I want to ask, if somebody else have an solution or clue for solve for my issue.

I am using for Python development an PyCharm editor. Whenever I run my code, which contains `os.system("xdg-open file.pdf")` from PyCharm, everything works as expected. But whenever I packed my code using PyInstaller, this command fails without any error message or clue, what happens, what to do or where to start to search to solve this issue (I know, that `os.system()` command didnt catch any message from launched command, but there isnt any clue *nowhere, at all*).

I have tried for sure everything, what was possible to do. I have tried other launchers, which I found, like `exo-open`, `mimeopen`; I have tried to run from Python code an external `bash` script, containing commands mentioned above in various combinations, I have tried to create an external Python binary (using PyInstaller), which only executes `os.system("xdg-open" + sys.argv[1])` command (because I call at other place of my program external binaries and it works fine), nowhere no clue, why that does not work.

When I try to use pure command `xdg-open file.pdf` from bash, everything works well. *)

Because I do my program for Linux and Windows as well, on Windows this malfunction is not present. There I use to view PDF file command `os.system("start './file.pdf'")` and it happens.

I am not sure, what is an origin of this issue, it could be PyInstaller issue, as well, as an system issue.

Have somebody similar experience and possibly some clue or solution? Your responses will be very welcome & thanks a lot!

Configuration:

- Linux Mint 18.2 64bit (kernel 4.8.0-53-generic)
- Xfce4 graphical environment
- Python 2.7
- PyCharm 2018 (closely latest release)
- Bash 4.3
- PyInstaller 3.4 (installed using `pip`)

Computer is Lenovo ThinkPad T410.

*) Maybe it could helps, or confuses more, but anyway: During testing process I have tried also run pure terminal from my program, to pass `xdg-open` command manually. But when I did it, there was no error message, but nothing happens. I have also tried to run PDF viewer straightforwardly, from common terminal everything works well, but from terminal opened by my program it runs PDF viewer, but with amount of GTK-related errors about missing icons (and `file.pdf` didn't open as well), so generally it fails (there was no icon present and no file opened (by the way with error message like "Open of mimetype *application/octet-stream* fails")). This behavior leads to some user/path/environment issue, but still, I have completely no clue, what happens and how to fix it.

P.S. I tried, of course, uncle Google for first, but without any success. Yes, it is possible, that I didn't found proper question to him, in that case please suggest me some ;)

Answer (score 0):

Since two months ago no response, so it looks like nobody is interested in this question.

I am still not unsure, what caused this issue, but it looks now, that it works, so just for evidence I write, what I think, that is possible source of this unpleasant behaviour.

I have recently updated kernel 4.8 to kernel 4.19.21 and I have tried as an PDF viewer/editor Foxit Reader 2.4.4.0911 (downloaded few days ago) (https://www.foxitsoftware.com/downloads/), since I have this configuration, opening PDFs from my program works, even I have still PyInstaller 3.4 in use.

I am not exactly sure, what was the origin of issue, because I have not setted Foxit Reader as an default PDF viewer and it opens in that, and also can be source of issue some kernel/intel video driver issue, maybe it is because I have dropped Xreader as an default PDF viewer. Maybe it was some issue with mimetypes (I ment, that for example DoubleCommander or Mutt dont respect system mimetypes settings and try to open files in program according their own will and I can still not figure out, why and how to change it), who knows, when I am with this issue alone.

In all cases, on Linux Mint 18.2 machine with configuration described above it now works, as expected.

Answer (score 0):

This is related to the PyInstaller issues mentioned here:
https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/3668

This should work for now:

```
myEnv = dict(os.environ)
lp_key = 'LD_LIBRARY_PATH'
lp_orig = myEnv.get(lp_key + '_ORIG')
if lp_orig is not None:
    myEnv[lp_key] = lp_orig
else:
    lp = myEnv.get(lp_key)
    if lp is not None:
        myEnv.pop(lp_key)

subprocess.Popen(["xdg-open", "file.pdf"], env=myEnv)
```